# How to prevent VSCode (Emmet) from expanding TypeScript type definitions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, emmet

In `.tsx` files, when writing a type definition containing a sub type, VSCode (Emmet) expands it as if it was a JSX tag. Does anybody know how to prevent this behaviour while keeping the functionality for standard JSX?

Example:

```
const a: MyType<Something
```

generates the following when typing the closing `>`:

```
const a: MyType<Something></Something>
```

While the expected result is:

```
const a: MyType<Something>
```

Note that this happens inside and outside of React components and JSX statements.

Comment: Instead of typing `>` just type `/` i should autocomplete the closing tag `>` and not expand that  and then remove `/`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a complete solution.

Comment: I would think ` "emmet.excludeLanguages": ["typescriptreact", "javascriptreact"],` in your settings would do it but they have no effect for me.  Perhaps you have better luck.

Comment: Yes, but that would completely disable Emmet in these `tsx` files which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It should be `type`, not `const`. That's not a valid location in syntax for defining TypeScript generic parameters.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're right but the behaviour I'm describing happens where it shouldn't regardless.

Comment: Updated my comment, thanks. Though, your example of Partial<int> is invalid, if you try `Partial<` followed by, for instance `ButtonHTMLAttributes`, you end up with `Partial<ButtonHTMLAttributes></ButtonHTMLAttributes>`.

Comment: hm. what happens for you if you do `const a: Partial<HTMLButtonElement`? For me it doesn't try to close it as a JSX tag pair. And is there any difference you observe in doing it in a new file with no open workspace versus in a file with a tsconfig? If so, what is in that tsconfig?